# Download button doesn't drop down

Tags: installation

The DOWNLOAD CIVICRM 5.49.1 button on the https://civicrm.org/download doesn't have any drop down options.

Comment: I was able to get the latest version using a URL format similar to previous versions: https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.49.1-wordpress.zip

Answer (score 2):

You can also find CiviCRM versions on the SourceForge. I'm sure this is a bug tho. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/

Answer (score 0):

The download button now has options. Someone has fixed it.